# How can I configure my mac to open files that have no extension in Sublime Text 2 (or another editor)

Tags: macos, file-extension

I want

```
open ~/.profile
```

to open my `.profile` file in Sublime Text 2. I know how to do this with .txt files for example, but I can't figure out how to do that with files that don't have an extension.

Comment: You can change the default application for the `public.plain-text` UTI by editing `com.apple.LaunchServices.plist` or by using duti or RCDefaultApp.

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about a command line, just set up Sublime Text 2's CLI. See [Sublime Text 2: OS X Command Line](http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/2/osx_command_line.html). Basically run:

> `ln -s "/Applications/Sublime Text 2.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl" ~/bin/subl`

Once you do that, you can simply open any files with:

> `subl ~/.profile`